# Simple Norm Inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I was looking at this paper https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:976120/FULLTEXT01.pdf

published in **AMM**, I was not getting the importance of this paper. What's motivation behind this? Why the author worked on this?

Theorem 1, I can say is stronger version of triangle inequality.

Can anybody please help me in this. Thanks in advance.